# Reducing multidimensional array to linear

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have asked a question similar to this, but none answered. Im guessing because it was too long that i wasnt able to fully state or make it clear to the general public. Anyways, Is there anyway into reducing an array like this

> Array( [0]=>Array( [id]=>name ) [1]=>Array( [id]=>name ) )

The above values came from.

```
$query=$this->db
            ->select('id,name')
            ->from('employees')
            ->get()
            ->result_array();
```

The query above results,

> Array([0]=>Array([id]=>1 [name]=>john))

Since i wanted to get all the rows without overwriting the previous rows resulted. I added this algo.

```
foreach($query as $row)
{   
$employee_list[] = array($row['id']=>$row['name']);                                     
}
```

Now the results are not overwritten so if i `print_r($employee_list);`
I would echo out, assume there are 2 rows in my employees table.

1-john,2-peter

> Array([1]=>Array([1]=>john) [2]=>Array([2]=>peter))

My question now is, how do i reduce the above resulted array to one dimensional/linear. Since the ID is stored as KEY and the id column is INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY so it doesnt have any duplicates which means for every row inserted the id will be incremented.

so it would be fine if the array i wanted would be.

> Array([1]=>john [2]=>peter)

Additional INFO: I am using codeigniter as my framework, so if there's any defined function in the CI library, it would help if anyone could tell me if there is any.

Comment: `$employee_list[$row['id']] = $row['name']` ?

Comment: Thanks! tested and it resulted to be a 1 dimensional array. I just realized why mine turned out the way it did. :) if you could write your answer as an answer i will accept it ASAP.

Comment: Just drop it, the question is too trivial (and tbh useless for the community) to leave it here.

Answer (score 0):

In old times you could use [mysql_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) which selects one column into single dimensional array.

However, it is deprecated since PHP 5.5.0 and the reference suggests using [mysqli_fetch_field](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php) (which forces you to make a select from the response as zerkms suggest in the comment) or [PDOStatement::fetchColumn](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) if you are willing to use PDO.